# Cannot build WSO2 BPMN service task .CAR file

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

I'm trying to create a Composite Application with my own service task as described in [WSO2 documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS360/Creating+a+BPMN+Process#CreatingaBPMNProcess-Creatingdeploymentartifacts)

I did all steps as described in the documentation but it doesn't show me `ServiceTask_Artifact` as a dependency in my Composite Application project.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Integration studio and it is already reported[1]. It will be fixed in future releases.

[1]. https://github.com/wso2/devstudio-tooling-ei/issues/386